# Getting wrong days crom calendar.getInstance

Tags: java, android

**Today's date:** `4/21/2016 thursday`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int weekOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);

Utilities.trace("MainActivity, year = " + year + " month = " + month + " day = " + weekOfDay);
```

But as a result I get `day = 3`. I don't understand why..

Comment: I would suspect a time zone issue

Answer (score 2):

You are printing weekOfDay not `day`

```
Utilities.trace("MainActivity, year = " + year + " month = " + month + " day = " + weekOfDay);
```

Change it to

```
Utilities.trace("MainActivity, year = " + year + " month = " + month + " day = " + day);
```

As `WeekOfDay` will start from 0, its showing 3 for Thursday

Answer (score 0):

In calendar month starts from 0 so add 1 in it

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int weekOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
```

and show it like this way

```
Utilities.trace("MainActivity, year = " + year + " month = " + month + " day = " + day);
```

So you will get the date 2014=4=21

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int weekOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);

    Utilities.trace("MainActivity, year = " + year + " month = " + month + " day = " + day);
```